# used java to make a websocket connetion failed

Tags: java, websocket

I'm new to java. and i doing performance testing on a websockt server. I need to make a websocket via java to communicate with server. 
  i used javax.websocket, but it always failed.
code as below:

```
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(); 
    String uri ="ws://127.0.0.1:8080"; 
    System.out.println("Connecting to"+ uri); 
    try { 
    session = container.connectToServer(MyClient.class, URI.create(uri)); 
      } catch (DeploymentException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

i used this to make the connection, and it sent something,but not meet my point.

i just get the following network package.

[image]

and if i use js code as below, and it make it..

```
var target='ws://localhost:7777';
var socket = io.connect(target);
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for previous post I made. It was for Server implementation. Now I changed my post for Client implementation.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem as well. If you get the HTTP Request out, the problem lies not in a missing dependency on the client endpoint side. But where *is* the problem? Do you get an error message? Then we need the stack trace. Or is there something else not working as intended? And, most important: Is your firewall blocking anything? Just to make sure make a test with it completely disabled.

Comment: i wonder if there is  possible to  make a standard websockt connection in java using some jar ?or need i to implement it myself?

Comment: Websockets are standardized in Java by JSR-356 (package `javax.websocket`), the reference implementation is *tyrus* (https://tyrus.java.net/). No need to implement anything by yourself. But please, can you answer all the questions in my previous comment? And put "*@Leviathan*" in front of your comments, that way I get highlighted that you wrote a comment and can respond faster.

Answer (score 0):

To call `getWebSocketContainer()` you need to have a least one container provider class listed in the file `META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider`.

For example, you could use `org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyContainerProvider`
or `org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager`. Make sure these classes are available to your project.

See documentation for more: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/ContainerProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

To create client endpoint you will need a client server. Here I shown an example with maven.

Add following dependencies in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then write following code

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WSClient {
    private static Object waitLock = new Object();

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received msg: " + message);
    }

    private static void wait4TerminateSignal() {
        synchronized (waitLock) {
            try {
                waitLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebSocketContainer container = null;//
        Session session = null;
        try {
            String url = "ws://localhost:8080/abcd/ratesrv";    //< Here goes your URL 
            container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            session = container.connectToServer(WSClient.class, URI.create(url));
            wait4TerminateSignal();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*If you are not using maven, just add all the jar files of tyrus to your path.*

Comment: i used this but cant create a valid connetion

Comment: are you able to create connection with javascript? What IDE you are using?

Comment: eclipse。 yes, made it using js。。

Comment: Although this doesn't really answer why the OP's code isn't working, this sample code *does* work. It just connects and sits there until you notify the `waitLock`. In the meantime, though, every message received will be output to the console. If you instead want this client to send a message (instead of waiting for the server to send one), you could do that in the `@OnOpen` handler with `session.getBasicRemote().sendText("testmsg");`. If you need more help for that, maybe afzalex can add an example of this to his answer.

Comment: here is the post, and it's refused by server.    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Connection:Upgrade
     Host:127.0.0.1:7777
    Origin:127.0.0.1:7777
    Sec-WebSocket-Key:8OVdMRB7okJwuOK26qfVrA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket.

Comment: in websocket io connection,first, client send a polling post, then recieved a reponse with a unique sid, then it send a post to change protocal from HTTP to websocket, then the connection created,  i used code afzalex posted, then ,it just send a post without any info...that maybe the problem, and i can't find a way to resolve it.